# Swift : View's frame getting altered when a subview is added

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I have a collection view and two container-views in a view which slides up (lets call it menugrid). When menugrid is slided up, the frame is set so that it covers the entire screen. I am trying to build a functionality where a user can drag and drop a UICollectionView cell onto a container-view. When I start drag and drop, the menugrid view comes back down to the initial location which is at the bottom of the screen.

Here is some code :

```
func handlePanForCell(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        let pressPoint: CGPoint =  gestureRecognizer.locationInView(gestureRecognizer.view)
        let localPoint : CGPoint = self.menuGridView.convertPoint(pressPoint, fromView: gestureRecognizer.view!)
        var cell : MenugridCollectionViewCell  = MenugridCollectionViewCell()
        if(gestureRecognizer.view is UICollectionViewCell){
            if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) {
                cell  =  gestureRecognizer.view as! MenugridCollectionViewCell
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cell.bounds.size);
                cell.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
                let cellImage : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                self.movingCell =  UIImageView.init(image: cellImage)
                self.movingCell?.alpha = 0.75
                //let cellFrameInSuperview : CGRect =  self.menuGridCollectionView.convertRect(cell.frame, toView: self.menuGridView)
                self.movingCell?.center =  localPoint
                //self.movingCell?.frame = cellFrameInSuperview
                self.view.addSubview(self.movingCell!)
            }
            if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed) {
                self.movingCell?.center = localPoint
                setMenuGridViewOnTop()
            }
            if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {

                // Check to see if the drop area is in the personalized info-area
                let isContaining =  self.menuGridView.convertRect(self.firstContainerView.frame, toView: self.menuGridView).contains(self.movingCell!.frame) || self.middleView.convertRect(self.secondInfoView.frame, toView: self.menuGridView).contains(self.movingCell!.frame)
                if isContaining
                {
                    if(self.middleView.convertRect(self.firstInfoView.frame, toView: self.view).contains(self.movingCell!.frame)) {
                        //let index = self.findIndexOfViewController(self.infoViewArray[0])
                        //let oldViewController : UIViewController = self.childViewControllers[Int(index)] as UIViewController
                        self.switchInfoViews(nil, toView: (gestureRecognizer.view as! MenugridCollectionViewCell).name!, atPosition: 0, parentView: "menuGridView")
                    }
                    else {
                        self.switchInfoViews(nil, toView: (gestureRecognizer.view as! MenugridCollectionViewCell).name!, atPosition: 1, parentView: "menuGridView")
                    }
                    //self.movingCell?.removeFromSuperview()
                }
                self.movingCell?.removeFromSuperview()
                self.movingCell = nil
                //setMenuGridViewOnTop()

                //self.view.viewWithTag(1000)?.removeFromSuperview()
                //self.view.viewWithTag(1001)?.removeFromSuperview()
                //self.middleView.alpha = 1
                //self.childViewControllers[0].view.alpha = 1
                //self.childViewControllers[1].view.alpha = 1
                //self.topView.alpha = 1
            }
        }
        //setMenuGridViewOnTop()
    }



//MARK: -  Switch Views
    func switchInfoViews(fromViewController : UIViewController?, toView : String, atPosition : CGFloat, parentView : String) {

        var newViewController : InfoViewController = InfoViewController()
        var storyBoardIdOfNewView =  String()
        if(toView == "Doctor"){
            newViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProviderSearchInfoViewControllerID") as! ProviderSearchInfoViewController
            storyBoardIdOfNewView = "ProviderSearchInfoViewControllerID"
        }
        else if(toView == "PayBill"){
            newViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PayBillInfoViewControllerID") as! PayBillInfoViewController
            storyBoardIdOfNewView = "PayBillInfoViewControllerID"
        }
        else if(toView == "Symptoms"){
            newViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SymptomsInfoViewControllerID") as! SymptomsInfoViewController
            storyBoardIdOfNewView = "SymptomsInfoViewControllerID"
        }
        else if(toView == "Handouts"){
            newViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PatientHandoutInfoViewControllerID") as! PatientHandoutInfoViewController
            storyBoardIdOfNewView = "PatientHandoutInfoViewControllerID"
        }
        else if(toView == "FirstAid"){
            newViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstAidInfoViewControllerID") as! FirstAidInfoViewController
            storyBoardIdOfNewView = "FirstAidInfoViewControllerID"
        }

        if(parentView == "menuGridView") {

                let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(storyBoardIdOfNewView)
                if(atPosition == 0){
                    self.firstContainerView.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
                    viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, (self.menuGridView.frame.width / 2) - 3, self.menuGridView.frame.height * 0.3)//self.firstContainerView.frame
                    self.firstContainerView.addSubview(viewController.view)
                }
                else {
                    self.secondContainerView.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
                    viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, (self.menuGridView.frame.width / 2) - 3, self.menuGridView.frame.height * 0.3)//self.secondContainerView.frame
                    self.secondContainerView.addSubview(viewController.view)
                }
            if(self.menuAtTop){
                self.setMenuGridViewOnTop()
            }
            }
            else if(parentView == "middleView"){

                if(!self.checkIfViewControllerIsAlreadyDisplayed(newViewController))
                {
                    fromViewController?.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
                    fromViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
                    fromViewController?.removeFromParentViewController()
                    self.movingCell?.removeFromSuperview()
                    newViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0 + atPosition * self.middleView.frame.size.width / 2, 0 , self.middleView.frame.size.width / 2, self.middleView.frame.size.height)
                    self.middleView.addSubview(newViewController.view)
                    self.addChildViewController(newViewController)
                    newViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
                    if(self.infoViewArray.count > 0) {
                        self.infoViewArray.removeAtIndex(Int(atPosition))
                        self.infoViewArray.insert(toView, atIndex: Int(atPosition))
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

What could be causing it ? I am stumped at why this would happen and would appreciate any help with this. Thank you.

Comment: There is no auto-layout set on the views. Layout is being set in code.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by removing AutoLayout from the project and resorting to setting layout in code.

I would still like to know why that happened as that would help me to understand AutoLayout better.